# How can I use multi condition in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I am using where condition to fitch the data where reseverId and sender id is equal to specific ids from fireStore
the cod is like this:
how can I use two defrent (where, can I use, and instade two where or there's somthing else)

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .where('resiverId', isEqualTo: resId)
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have above is totally valid query. You would just need to build an `index` to run it. When you run the above query for the first time, you will see a error in your debug console along with a long URL. Just copy and paste the URL to your browser. It will take you to the page to build that specific index to run your query.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @dshukertjr, your query is valid and will require you to create an index to work.

However, what is not possible (at the moment) in Firestore is range filters **(example: <, <=, >, >=)** on multiple fields.  An *equal/not equal* on one field with *a range filter* on another works.

Please refer to the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries.